# Using RegExp in express routes

Tags: regex, node.js, express, request, middleware

I'm trying to write a middleware, that will do something (e.g make logs) for each `/api/*` request.

I wrote follow middleware, but it's not working for `/api/me`

```
var app = require('express');
app.all(/\/api/, function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the middleware is called before your `/api/` routes are defined, and that you call `next()`, otherwise the request will hang.

```
var app = require('express');
app.use('/api/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('hello');
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks) Yes, you're right about _"Make sure the middleware is called before your `/api/` routes are defined_. Here was my problem.